# Adding lines to separate table rows

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow, line

Which command to use to add row separating lines as shown in the bottom most image (sample) ?
I was using \hline , but in case of multiple rows it will cut the column name. I have added my code progress. Thank You

[image]

```
 \begin{center}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1 \textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{   *{16}{c | } } 

 \multirow{2}{*} {Instance} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*} {Single Level Linear Formulation} }
            & \multicolumn{8}{c }{Scatter Search}                    \\
  \hline         
  &  &  &    & &  &    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Best}   & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Average}   \\ 
  
     &  LeaderObj LB &   LeaderObj UB & Follower Obj & \%GAP  & CPU(s)  
    & Best OFL &   \%GAP LB & \%GAP UB  &  Average OFL  & Average OFF &  \%GAP UB & \%GAP LB &  CPU(s)     
    \\ 
  \hline
test 90k20ta1 & 1935 & 2094 & 1169 & 8.22 & time       
  \\ 
test 90k20ta2 & 1968 & 2091 & 1173.6 & 6.25 & time       
 \\ 
 
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: Please tell us which doument class you employ and which packages need to be loaded, and please show the code employed in, say, the the five or six lines of the table. A separate issue: Would you like to align all numbers on their (implicit or explicit) decimal point markers?

Comment: I haven't employed the code, this is a reference document that I have which I am trying to replicate. Aligning the numbers would be great as well , I saw somewhere using {s} instead of {c}.

Comment: So you need a lot more code than just for horizontal lines that don't intersect with horizontal lines? Please advise.

Comment: Thanks alot for your time , I have added my progress so far @Mico.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to suggest that you employ the `rotating` package and its `sidewaystable` environment to typeset the table in landscape orientation. Second, don't use the Procrustean bed known as the `adjustbox` environment; instead, employ a `tabularx` environment and allow automatic line breaking while also centering the column contents. Third, don't use any vertical rules, and replace `\hline` and `\cline` with the macros of the `booktabs` package to obtain well-spaced horizontal lines. Trust me, the vertical lines won't be missed. Fourth and last (but not least), use the `S` column type of the `siunitx` package to align numbers in selected columns on their implicit or explicit decimal markers.

In the following example, the `C` column type -- which is a centered version of the `X` column type that's provided by the `tabularx` package -- is the default for the 13 data columns. Whenever a `T` column type (which is based on the `S` column type mentioned in the preceding paragraph) is used, be sure to "wrap" the corresponding header cell in an `\mC` wrapper. Do notice `\mC{Follower Obj}` and `\mC{\%GAP}` in the code below as examples of such "wraps".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters appropriately
\usepackage{rotating, % for 'sidewaystable' environment
            booktabs, % for well-spaced horizontal rules
            tabularx, % for 'tabularx' environment
            ragged2e, % for '\Centering' macro
            siunitx}  % for 'S' columntype (and 'table-format' option)
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]} % align on (explicit or implicit) decimal marker

\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}C@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\hyphenation{leader-obj} % permit hyphenation between 'leader' and 'obj'

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default value: 6pt

\caption{A table with 14 columns\strut} % choose real caption as needed

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ @{} % occupy full width (height) of text block
    l      % left alignment, no line breaking allowed
    CC     % use 'C' col. type for first two data columns
    T{4.1} % 4 integer digits, 1 decimal digit
    T{2.2} % 2 integer digits, 2 decimal digits
    *{11}{C} % remaining columns (respecify as needed)
    @{} } 

\toprule
Instance & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Single Level Linear Formulation}
         & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Scatter Search} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-6} \cmidrule(l){7-14} 
& & & & & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Best} & 
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{Average}   \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){7-9} \cmidrule(l){10-14}
& LeaderObj LB & LeaderObj UB & \mC{Follower Obj} & \mC{\%GAP} & CPU(s) 
& Best OFL & \%GAP LB & \%GAP UB 
& Average OFL & Average OFF & \%GAP UB & \%GAP LB & CPU(s) \\ 
\midrule
test 90k20ta1 & 1935 & 2094 & 1169   &  8.22 & time & \dots   
\\ 
test 90k20ta2 & 1968 & 2091 & 1173.6 & 17.24 & time & \dots    
\\ 
\dots 
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response ! :)